# Ionic Cordova: FileTransfer not working. Wrong configuration?

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on an android app and I have to download a file to the local storage of the phone.
I'm using this tutorial https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-transfer/.
I've copied the download() method.

I followed this guide but the method always returns an error without any message or status. So, I assume there is a problem in the configuration of my project.

The download is performed on a class like this:

```
import { File, FileWriter } from '@ionic-native/file';
import { FileTransfer, FileTransferObject  } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer';
...
@Component({
  selector: 'balise',
  templateUrl: 'balise.html'
})
export class BaliseComponent implements OnInit {
  fileTransfer: FileTransferObject;
  constructor( private http : HTTP, public loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private transfer : FileTransfer, private file : File ) 
  {
    console.log('Hello BaliseComponent');
    this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();
  }
  OnSaveClick(){
    console.log(this.fileTransfer);
    const url = 'http://www.example.com/file.pdf';
    this.fileTransfer.download(url, this.file.dataDirectory + 'file.pdf')
    .then((entry) => {
        console.log('download complete: ' + entry.toURL());
    })
   .catch ( (error) => {
      console.log('download error');
      console.log(error.error);
      console.log(error.status);
      console.log(error.headers);
    });
  }
}
```

However, the OnSaveClick() callback always produce an empty error.
Moreover, I've declared File and FileTransfer as providers in the "app.module.ts" file.
So, the example from the tutorial always failed on my project, without any message or stack trace. I don't know what is wrong.

Have you any idea ?
I'm using ionic cli 4.8, cordova 8.1.2 and java 8.

Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean by empty error? Please post the output of `console.log(error)` in your catch block.

Comment: I am using this file transfer in y project. try this: remove '
    this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create();' in your constructor and oninit(); in your on OnSaveClick() function, create a variable for example: const transfer = this.fileTransfer = this.transfer.create(); 

the rest seems to me correct